# How do I refresh the Properties Window in a Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio, inotifypropertychanged, visual-studio-extensions, system.componentmodel

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension that allows editing the properties of an object in the Properties Window. I use the ITrackSelection interface to select the object I want to edit, and it all works fine, the properties are shown in the window and I can edit them.

However, I can't make Visual Studio refresh the Properties Window when a property is changed externally. I tried implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, but the PropertyChanged event is never subscribed. I also tried implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor and returning custom PropertyDescriptor objects with overrides for AddValueChanged and SupportsChangeEvents, but those are never called.

What I'm missing? How can I tell Visual Studio that a property of my object has changed and the Property Window has to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

[IVsUIShell.RefreshPropertyBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuishell.refreshpropertybrowser(v=vs.120).aspx) should do the trick and update the Property Window.